# Java lib to work on mySQL with object oriented syntax?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Beginner in SQL, coming from MongoDB.

I see libs that write SQL queries with Strings like:

```
String sql =
    "SELECT id, category, duedate " +
    "FROM tasks " +
    "WHERE category = :category";
```

then one must take this `sql String` and write something like: `List<Task> tasks = con.createQuery(sql);`

My question:
Imagine a db made of tables where each line in the table is considered an object.
Is there a library for mySQL where the syntax would be more like:

```
List<Object> results = db.query().select(Object.oneField).where(Object.oneField.equals("myString").from(db.MyTable);
```

Note: the mySQL db is already created, I am not the owner.

Comment: The most 'popular' such library is probably Hibernate. In any case the term/category you are looking for is [Object-relational mapping (ORM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping), e.g. search: "Java ORM". There are a bunch of different approaches / variants - [get looking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software)!

Comment: Can downvoters explain their vote in the comments? Why is this question not a valid? This is a guenine coding question I have, and I thank user2864740 for giving me pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Hibernate is what you are looking for.

At a very beginners level its like..

`//create a user(Entity) object and set its properties
   User user = new User();
   user.setName("xyz");
   user.setCity("New Delhi");`

and then you go on persisting(saving) the object to the database which will allow you to save the user properties in the database.

`//get hibernate specific SessionFactory object
session.persist(user); //this will make your object's properties persist in the database`

Take a look at Hibernate docs for detailed info.